# Using shiny's renderUI in Module

Tags: r, module, shiny

this is my first question at stackoverflow. I have a problem with modules and renderUI in shiny (1.0.5).

When I use renderUI in

```
#### Main Part

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  uiOutput("DynamicContent")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  S_A <- selectInput("S_A_Input"  ,"Change Me for print message",choices=1:3 )

  output$DynamicContent <- renderUI({
    tagList(S_A) 
  })

  observe({
    print(input$S_A_Input) 
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

then changing the selectInput will cause changing input$S_A_Input, so the print will occur. That's fine.

On the other hand, input$S_A_Input seems not to work, if I work with modules:

```
### Module Part

Module_YYY_Server <- function(input, output, session){ 

  S_A <- selectInput("S_A_Input"  ,"Change Me for print message",choices=1:3 )

  output$DynamicContent <- renderUI({
    tagList(S_A) 
  })

  observe({
    print(input$S_A_Input) 
  })


}


Module_YYY_Ui <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id) # Creates Namespace

  tagList(
    uiOutput("DynamicContent" %>% ns)
  )

}
```

And then calling the module.

```
#### Main Part

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  Module_YYY_Ui("YYY")  
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  callModule(Module_YYY_Server,"YYY")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I haven't found a solution to this behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party but this is another option to solve your problem using

> session$ns("id")

Here how it looks like:

```
Module_YYY_Server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$DynamicContent <- renderUI({
    selectInput(session$ns("S_A_Input"), "Change Me for print message", choices = 1:3)
    })

  output$text <- renderText({
    req(input$S_A_Input)
    input$S_A_Input})
}


Module_YYY_Ui <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id) # Creates Namespace

  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("DynamicContent")),
    textOutput(ns("text"))
  )
}


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  Module_YYY_Ui("YYY")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  callModule(Module_YYY_Server,"YYY")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is based on the example [here](https://gist.github.com/tbadams45/38f1f56e0f2d7ced3507ef11b0a2fdce)

Answer (score 3):

While I am sure your example is simplified, If your `input$S_A_Input` is not changing based on what you are doing, as is the case in your example, I would not recommend using `renderUI`. Regardless of that, the reason that your input is not printing is because you are not generating it as an output.

```
Module_YYY_Server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$DynamicContent <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    tagList(
      selectInput("S_A_Input" %>% ns, "Change Me for print message",choices=1:3 )
    ) 
  })

  output$text <- renderText({input$S_A_Input})



}


Module_YYY_Ui <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id) # Creates Namespace

  tagList(
    uiOutput("DynamicContent" %>% ns),
    textOutput("text" %>% ns)
  )

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.: If I change anything at selectInput, there wont be any renderText. It seems, that shiny doesn't see input$S_A_Input as an reactive...

Comment: Check my edit. I think the issue is that it was defined outside of the reactive

Comment: Still doen't seem to work. Everytime I change my selectInput, say from 1 to 3, there is no change in output. What I see is, that the selectInput will be created, but there is no input$S_A_input

Comment: alright, I figured out what the issue was. I forgot to assign `ns <- session$ns` inside the `renderUI` call. Anytime you generate the `ui` inside of the server portion of the module, you have to add that code to the top of the `renderUI` call. Also note that I added `%>% ns` to the `inputId` argument of the `selectInput` inside `renderUI`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, if it solved your problem, please mark it as correct! Thanks!