# sliderInput with renderUI returns NULL in modularized R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a modularized R Shiny app in which a `sliderInput()` is created within `renderUI()` so that the value can be passed to further processing (here, a `renderPrint()`). First, I tested the construct in a simple app composed of a `global.R`, a `ui.R` and a `server.R`, where it works as expected (i.e. on slider modification, the correct slider input is printed):

**global.R**

```
library(shiny)
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(3, 
                  uiOutput("ui")),
           column(3,
                  verbatimTextOutput("dynamic_value")))))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("dynamic", "The slider:",
                min = 1, 
                max = 20,
                value = 10)
  })
  
  output$dynamic_value <- renderPrint({
    str(input$dynamic)
  })
  
})
```

Then, I transferred this construct to a modularized app, in which--to my surprise--the value passed from the slider to the text output is `NULL` instead of the actual value from the slider input:

**global.R**

```
library(shiny)

# load module
source("test_module.R")
```

**test_ui.R**

```
test_module_ui(id = "test")
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(navbarPage(title = "Dynamic sliderInput",
                             tabPanel("Panel",
                                      source("test_ui.R",
                                             local = TRUE)$value))))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(test_module, "test")
  })
```

**test_module.R**

```
test_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id) # namespace
  
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           uiOutput(ns("ui"))),
    column(3,
           verbatimTextOutput(ns("dynamic_value")))
    )
}

test_module <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("dynamic", "The slider:",
                min = 1, 
                max = 20,
                value = 10)
  })
  
  output$dynamic_value <- renderPrint({
    str(input$dynamic)
  })
}
```

Does someone know what is misspecified here? Any hints are highly appreciated--thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898569/using-shinys-renderui-in-module), you have to use `session$ns()` in the `renderUI()`:

```
test_module_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(session$ns("dynamic"), "The slider:",
                min = 1, 
                max = 20,
                value = 10)
  })
```

Comment: Indeed! That's the solution! Thank you, HubertL! And sorry for that I overlooked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898569/using-shinys-renderui-in-module) (honestly, I searched deeply)...